# How to use a UserForm to select a worksheet from selected workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro which allows a user to update a master workbook (where the macro is located) from a specific workbook and worksheet. The workbook and worksheet names can vary, so I call this UserForm from code adapted from [the ozgrid forum](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=192585):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MyFile = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    MySheet = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Stopped = True
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Me.Label1.Caption = "Please select one of the following files and Worksheets..."
    With Me.ComboBox1
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
            .AddItem wkb.Name
        Next wkb
    End With
    MyFile = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    With Me.ComboBox2
        For Each sht In Application.Worksheets
            .AddItem sht.Name
        Next sht
    End With
    MySheet = Me.ComboBox2.Value
End Sub
```

Now the problem is with the module in the master workbook that calls the user form. I get a type mismatch error with this bit: Set wb1 = MyFile

Here is the rest of the module:

```
Option Explicit

Public MyFile As String
Public Stopped As Boolean

Sub Update_Master()
    Stopped = False
    UserForm1.Show
    If Stopped Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox MyFile

' Update_Master Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim TargetFile As Variant
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws1LRow As Long, ws2LRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ws1LCol As Long, ws2LCol As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean, matchFound As Boolean

    '~~> Set EOD Workbook
    Set wb1 = MyFile
    Set ws1 = MySheet
    '~~> Get the last Row and Last Column
    With wb1
        ws1LRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws1LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    '~~> Set Master Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("MoO - Master List - TEST.xlsm")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("CM List")
    '~~> Get the last Row and Last Column
    With ws2
        ws2LRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws2LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    '~~> Loop Through Cells of Col E in workbook A and try and find it
    '~~> in Col E of workbook B
    For i = 2 To ws1LRow
        SearchString = ws1.Range("E" & i).Value

        Set aCell = ws2.Columns(5).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        ExitLoop = False

        '~~> If match found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            matchFound = True

            '~~> Then compare all columns
            For j = 6 To ws1LCol
                If ws1.Cells(i, j).Value <> ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value Then
                    matchFound = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            '~~> If all columns matched then write to Col A/B
            If matchFound = False Then
                ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, 12).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 12).Value
                ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, 13).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 13).Value
            End If

            '~~> Find Next Match
            Do While ExitLoop = False
                Set aCell = ws2.Columns(5).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                '~~> If match found
                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                    matchFound = True

                    '~~> Then compare all columns
                    For j = 6 To ws1LCol
                        If ws1.Cells(i, j).Value <> ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value Then
                            matchFound = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next

                    '~~> If all columns matched then write to Col A/B
                    If matchFound = False Then
                        ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, 12).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 12).Value
                        ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, 13).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 13).Value
                    End If
                Else
                    ExitLoop = True
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am an amateur and have been trying to piece this together from snippets of code I found here and elsewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Set` `wb1 = MyFile` with `Set wb1=Workbooks(myFile)`

Comment: depends if its already open. But yeah, cant assign a string to a workbook type. Type mismatch just told you the error, and you even get the faulty error line. First thing to do is check if both sides of the = are same type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gordon, but that still doesn't work, unfortunately. I did find a way with this

Comment: ... `Set wb1 = Workbooks(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value)' but now it is set as the Master Workbook even when I select a different workbook. When I step through the code, it goes back to the userform code but does not bring up the form - so I guess it determines the values all over again for each ComboBox. I am closer, but still stumped. Isn't there a way to declare the variable from the values selected in the UserForm and then pass them to the module? Setting them as Public or Global maybe?

Comment: Update: I finally got the UserForm and module to work together by using Me.Hide instead of Unload Me in the UserForm, which allowed me to set the selected Workbook and Worksheet as objects in the module. If anyone wants to see the code, just reply to this thread.